# Detect all touch locations in View with fast finger movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, cgpoint

I was wondering, if there is a way to recognize every single location of UITouch.

Following my finger location in touchesMoved like:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
```

I am having problems, with detecting "p" location if I move my finger fast. It just wont read every single X or Y position, but it will drop some.

Example:
I am following my touch location with NSLog, and if I move finger fast down the iPad, NSLog message is showing me Y location like: ... 281,301,322,346,375...

Answer (score 1):

This is the internal behaviour of the framework. You can safely assume intermediate points by following slope of a line. I mean your start location is (x1,y1) and end location is (x2,y2) then you can find all intermediate points.

When you will change the direction or path, you will get the new point in touchesMoved.

Comment: I understand what are you saying. But haven't found a good solution for it. I am tracing touch location to make  hitTest, if my touch collide with some view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gesture to get the location using below code

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
            [gr addTarget:self action:@selector(userLongPressed:)];
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

then in userLongPressed method :

```
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
```

NSLog point will give you all locations......

Please let me know if u want any more information..

Comment: NSLog is giving me nan result, if I try to print x and y locations?

Comment: use : if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
}

Comment: It behaves strange. Some times locations of x and y are bellow zero and they are the same all the time. But sometimes i get the right location, but result is the same as it was, when i was using touchesMoved, X and Y locations still dropping/increasing for more than 1.